# RC circuit - phase current

Tags: capacitor, ltspice, remote-control, passive-filter, phasor

I have a simple RC circuit as below :

[image]

I'm trying to visualize current curve and voltage curve (Vout and I(R1)) vs Vin using LtSpice and I obtain the result below:

[image]

It's OK that the Vout is leading Vin. However, I do not understand why the current curve I(R1) is completely out of phase with Vout. Any one have explanation for that ? Thanks for your support.

Comment: The voltage across the resistor is in phase with the current through it.

Comment: @Chu: Thanks for your answer. Yes It must be in phase. But I don't understand why I obtain the current (I(R1)) and Vout out of phase. Is there any explanation ? Or How I can fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: If the current's positive direction is defined, in your simulation, as from ground to Vout that's what you get.

Comment: Turn the resistor around 180 degrees and you'll get the results you expect.

Comment: When you use the current probe on LTSpice on that resistor, which direction does the tip of the arrow point?

Answer (score 1):

[image: the same simulationvia LTspice]

I simulated the same circuit and current seems fine and I used LTspice XVII. Maybe the issue is your version of LTspice. I think you might try to delete your version and upload the latest again.I hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: Now try rotating R1 180 degrees and reconnecting and what do you get?

Comment: Yep I got  my current out of phase.I didnt know that Ltspice has this issue.The 'plus' terminal of a resistor isn't shown on the schematic so you have no good way of knowing which direction the current actually is. It is annoying :/

Comment: All 2-pin bidirectional components in all sims have this "issue". Some explicitly show + as in inductors, resistors and capacitors don't. Personally I think they should.

Comment: @DamlaCelik It's no issue, it's standard SPICE convention since 40+ years ago: two pin elements have a pre-defined direction of current as a convenience for the matrix solver. Elements with more than two pins consider the current as going into the pin. And, as a general rule, don't rush to blame the tool ("*Maybe the issue is your version of LTspice*", or whatever other simulator); instead, try to first learn what that tool does and how.

Comment: @Andyaka: I think you for your answer. It resolves my issue. I have just rotate the R1 like you tell me and all it's OK.